# how to scroll divs on fixed background in intersection observer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, intersection-observer

As you can see in the snippet when the specific div comes in middle of the main the background image changes. I used the intersection observer to perform this functionality.Now, the issue is background image changing functionality is working perfectly in snippet but the background div is not fixed i want the background image div fixed and sections scrolls on it because i'll embed this codebase into my webpage.When the specific div comes in center the background image changes.

```js
      const bgEl = document.querySelector(".main");

function createObserver(el) {
  let observer;
  let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px"
  };

  function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        const url = entry.target.getAttribute("BGurl");
        bgEl.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
        entry.target.style.opacity = 1;
      }
    });
  }

  observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
  observer.observe(el);
  return observer;
}

(function() {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".main .section");
  const observers = Array.from(sections).map(function(section) {
    createObserver(section);
  });
})();
```

```css
.section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100% 100% !important;
}

.text {
  margin: auto;
}

.text p {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 149%;
  color: #263244;
}

.text h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.text .story-detail {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(76.31% 191.89% at 13.43% 22.19%, rgba(226, 228, 231, 0.8) 0%, rgba(228, 228, 229, 0.368) 100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  padding: 23px;
}

.text .story-description {
  width: 321px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(76.31% 191.89% at 13.43% 22.19%, rgba(226, 228, 231, 0.8) 0%, rgba(228, 228, 229, 0.368) 100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  padding: 23px;
}

.BG {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">
  <div class="BG">
  </div>
  <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.postimg.cc/9QYL3ytR/mobile-camp.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div style="margin-inline: 20px">
        <h1>Our Story</h1>
        <div class="story-detail">
          <p>
            We saw a gap between what people need and what banks offer. It means millions of us aren't getting the banking experience we deserve for different reasons.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.postimg.cc/9QYL3ytR/mobile-camp.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div style="margin-inline: 20px">
        <div class="story-description">
          <p>
            Traditional banks don’t focus on customers' experience, their systems may be slow and outdated, they may prioritize a specific group of people, or perhaps they lack the ability to innovate, and so on.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.postimg.cc/cLPLS8xW/mobile-desert.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div style="margin-inline: 20px">
        <div class="story-description">
          <p>
            So since we're passionate about solving problems and bridging gaps, we looked into and identified the challenges and capabilities we'll need to build a bank here in the Kingdom.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.postimg.cc/mZnqV38T/mobile-birds.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div style="margin-inline: 20px">
        <div class="story-description">
          <p>
            With the best local and international expertise, we began building an innovative digital bank designed by and for the people. We believe that the most effective way to build a bank for people is to do it with them. This is our philosophy. So, we started
            building it with the help of people like you.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.postimg.cc/k513m0Fb/mountain.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div style="margin-inline: 20px">
        <div class="story-description">
          <p>
            At D360, innovation starts with someone’s passion for improving financial services. To that person, we say: Never stop offering solutions to your needs. These solutions will not only benefit you, but will significantly impact the lives of millions.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting the background image on the .BG div instead of the .main one: `...querySelector(".BG")` instead of `...querySelector(".main")`.

Comment: @Bqardi yes it works.The problem is that the position of BG is fixed. So, it is interuppting the other sections of the page like header footer etc. Is there any way to fix it. So that if the last section reaches the position of the BG changes?